# Is a portable air conditioner supposed to make a buzzing/rattling noise?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a brand new Olympia Splendid Ellisse HP portable heat pump/air conditioner and it makes a vibrating buzzing noise when it is on doing the cooling. I understand there should be some compressor noise, so is this vibrating buzz normal for portable air conditioners? It sounds exactly the like the buzzing from an old fridge... This is a brand new reputable portable air conditioner...

Comment: Do you have access to an a-c volt meter to test your power at the receptacle?

Comment: No but I suppose I could get one... How exactly do they work and does it specifically have to be a volt meter?

Comment: Does the AC volt meter have anything to do with the buzzing?

Comment: The purpose of the voltmeter would be to measure your voltage to see if it is in the range specified by the manufacturer. If the voltage would be below the minimum specified, then *maybe* it could cause the buzzing.

Comment: As my PC plugged into an UPS is on the same breaker as the AC would the UPS logging give some idea of what the voltage is doing on this circuit or will I need to test the exact jack the AC is plugged into? Exactly what sort of volt meter do I need and how do I use it?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a portable air conditioner, and it makes the sound that you describe.  Much like an old refrigerator combined with the noise produced from the fan moving air.  I believe this is normal and would not be a concern for me.

Comment: Do you know what part of the air conditioner makes the noise? Is it the compressor that vibrates?

Comment: There is a fan that creates some noise as well as the compressor that vibrates while it is running.

Comment: It definitely sounds like part of the compressor vibrating, but what exactly causes the vibrating buzz?

Comment: Compressors are the normal source of the noise , the compressor motor is fully enclosed and it vibrates when running almost all are mounted on rubber for this very reason. Sounds like a fridge because the same thing is happening, Freon is getting compressed , then cooled , then it is released to a lower pressure state creating the cold, then back to the compressor.